Use unicode character with pdfLatex
I'm not using XeLatex or LuaLatex. Though I would want to use the unicode symbol: U+03D0 (some kind of beta) in my documents.
I mean that I want a way to use this symbol, even if I have to use a command: I just want a way to include it (I don't necessarily want to type ϐ in my document).

Do you have a font in mind that provides this glyph?

A quick check shows that the character is in a wide range of fonts including a number of the TTF fonts included in the TeX distribution.

I didn't found many, working with pdfTeX I mean.

It seems to be in 'MinionPro'. I don't see why it solves my problem, though, if I don't want my document to be written in that police.

The short answer is that you can’t. pdfTeX is essentially Unicode ignorant and while it’s possible to get it to figure out what to do with Unicode input, it doesn’t have a mechanism for doing Unicode output.
So your options would be to either switch to a Unicode-aware TeX engine (i.e., XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX), or find or make an 8-bit font that includes this character.

I understand, but it seems rather incredible that there is no way to use this pretty common mathematical character, doesn't it?

It’s an unusual alternate form of β. I don’t think I have ever seen ϐ appear anywhere but Unicode character tables.
